# What is a "back counter" in this context?

Tags: meaning

I have in front of me instructions for preparing ice skates for individual use. The first four steps are:

> 1.) Properly measure for correct skate size.
>
> 2.) Preheat warming oven to 200 degrees Farenheight.
>
> 3.) Place open boots in oven for 8 minutes.
>
> 4.) Remove boots from oven and flex back counters open.

I have no idea what the fourth step is asking of me, as I am not familiar with the term "back counter." What do you think it means?

Comment: Ice skates have something called "heel counters."  I don't know what those are, but you're supposed to flex those backward.  In other words, the *back* goes with *flex*, not with *counters*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be specific to ice skates. Shoes have something called **heel counter** (or simply **counter**).

> heel counter: a piece of leather forming the back of a shoe or boot

([WordNet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heel+counter))

I've seen "back counter" used in online shop product descriptions where the seller's mother tongue wasn't English. This image is from a Chinese shop:

[image]

Here's another image where the word **"counter"** is used instead:

[image]